# 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::appends()' error in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a pagination for my Laravel project which will search market products from my database and show data. But I am getting the below error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::appends()

Here is my Method:

```
@section('markets-pagination')
   @if(isset($searched_market) && $searched_market->count()>0)
        {{$searched_market->appends(
        [
                    'category'=>app('request')->input('category'),
                    'keyword'=>app('request')->input('keyword')
                    ]
                    )->render()}}
    @endif
@stop
```

Here is Rendering Option:

```
@section('markets-pagination')
    {{$markets->render()}}
@stop
@section('market-name')
    @if(isset($market_name))
        @foreach($market_name as $item)
            <h3>{{$item->market_type}}</h3>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <h3>Showing All Listings</h3>
    @endif

@stop
```

This is Search Controller:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    private $request;

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * Some values for the menu etc
         */
        $menu_items = MarketType::markets();
        //$market_type = MarketType::marketName($id);

        $this->request = $request;
        /**
         * Taking input from the search form fields
         */
        $keyword = $this->request['keyword'];
        $category = $this->request['category'];
        //dd($keyword);
        /**
         * Retrieving data from the database
         */

        //dd($searched_market->items);
        if ($keyword != null && $category != null) {
            $searched_market = Market::searchBoth($keyword, $category);
        } else if ($keyword != null) {
            $searched_market = Market::searchKeyword($keyword);
        } else if ($category != null) {
            //dd('both');
            $searched_market = Market::searchCategory($category);
        } else {
            $searched_market = '';
        }
        //dd($searched_market->toSql());
        return view('frontend.search.product')
            ->with('menu', $menu_items)
            ->with('searched_market', $searched_market);   
    }
}
```

This is the category:

```
public function scopeSearchCategory($query, $category)
    {

        $this->category = $category;
        return $query->join('market_type_id', 'market.id', '=', 'market_type_id.market_id')
            ->join('market_type', 'market_type.id', '=', 'market_type_id.market_type_id')
            ->where('market_type.id', $this->category)
            ->select(['market.*', 'market_type.image'])
            ->distinct()
            ->paginate(12);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `paginate()` or `get()` in your [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes) functions as it will always returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

Remove `->paginate(12);` from your `scopeSearchCategory` scope and use it in your Controller as:

```
$searched_market = Market::searchCategory($category)->paginate(12);
```